# Is there a way to get information about kubernetes cronjob timetable?

Tags: kubernetes, cron, job-scheduling, k8s-cronjobber

I'd like to get information about k8s cronjob time.
There are so many jobs in my k8s program.
So It's hard to count what time there are focused on.
I want to distribute my jobs evenly.
Is there are way to count cronjob time or sort by time?

Comment: Do you want to know how long the `CronJob` task was running or when was the `Last Schedule Time` ?

Comment: No. I just want to get sorted timetable of my CronJob!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried to find a suitable tool that can help with your case.
Unfortunately, I did not find anything suitable and easy to use at the same time.

It is possible to use `Prometheus + Grafana` to monitor `CronJobs` e.g using this [Kubernetes Cron and Batch Job monitoring](https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/10884) dashboard.
However, I don't think you will find any useful information in this way, just a dashboard that displays the number of `CronJobs` in the cluster.

---

For this reason, I decided to write a Bash script that is able to display the last few `CronJobs` run in a readable manner.

As described in the [Kubernetes CronJob documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/):

> A CronJob creates Jobs on a repeating schedule.

To find out how long a specific [Job](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/) was running, we can check its `startTime` and `completionTime` e.g. using the commands below:

```
# kubectl get job <JOB_NAME> --template '{{.status.startTime}}'      #  "startTime"
# kubectl get job <JOB_NAME> --template '{{.status.completionTime}}' # "completionTime"
```

To get the duration of `Jobs` in seconds, we can convert `startTime` and `completionTime` dates to **epoch**:

```
# date -d "<SOME_DATE> +%s
```

And this is the entire Bash script:
**NOTE:** We need to pass the namespace name as an argument.

```
#!/bin/bash
# script name: cronjobs_timetable.sh <NAMESPACE>
namespace=$1

for cronjob_name in $(kubectl get cronjobs -n $namespace --template '{{range .items}}{{.metadata.name}}{{"\n"}}{{end}}'); do
    echo "===== CRONJOB_NAME: ${cronjob_name} ==========="

    printf "%-15s %-15s %-15s %-15s\n" "START_TIME" "COMPLETION_TIME" "DURATION" "JOB_NAME"
    for job_name in $(kubectl get jobs -n $namespace --template '{{range .items}}{{.metadata.name}}{{"\n"}}{{end}}' | grep -w "${cronjob_name}-[0-9]*$"); do

        startTime="$(kubectl get job ${job_name} -n $namespace --template '{{.status.startTime}}')"
        completionTime="$(kubectl get job ${job_name} -n $namespace --template '{{.status.completionTime}}')"
        if [[ "$completionTime"  == "<no value>" ]]; then
            continue
        fi
        duration=$[ $(date -d "$completionTime" +%s) - $(date -d "$startTime" +%s) ]
        printf "%-15s %-15s %-15s %-15s\n" "$(date -d ${startTime} +%X)" "$(date -d ${completionTime} +%X)" "${duration} s" "$job_name"
    done
done
```

By default, this script only displays the last three `Jobs`, but it may by modified in the Job configuration using the `.spec.successfulJobsHistoryLimit` and `.spec.failedJobsHistoryLimit` fields (for more information see [Kubernetes Jobs History Limits](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/#jobs-history-limits))

We can check how it works:

```
$ ./cronjobs_timetable.sh default
===== CRONJOB_NAME: hello ===========
START_TIME      COMPLETION_TIME DURATION        JOB_NAME
02:23:00 PM     02:23:12 PM     12 s            hello-1616077380
02:24:02 PM     02:24:13 PM     11 s            hello-1616077440
02:25:03 PM     02:25:15 PM     12 s            hello-1616077500
===== CRONJOB_NAME: hello-2 ===========
START_TIME      COMPLETION_TIME DURATION        JOB_NAME
02:23:01 PM     02:23:23 PM     22 s            hello-2-1616077380
02:24:02 PM     02:24:24 PM     22 s            hello-2-1616077440
02:25:03 PM     02:25:25 PM     22 s            hello-2-1616077500
===== CRONJOB_NAME: hello-3 ===========
START_TIME      COMPLETION_TIME DURATION        JOB_NAME
02:23:01 PM     02:23:32 PM     31 s            hello-3-1616077380
02:24:02 PM     02:24:34 PM     32 s            hello-3-1616077440
02:25:03 PM     02:25:35 PM     32 s            hello-3-1616077500
===== CRONJOB_NAME: hello-4 ===========
START_TIME      COMPLETION_TIME DURATION        JOB_NAME
02:23:01 PM     02:23:44 PM     43 s            hello-4-1616077380
02:24:02 PM     02:24:44 PM     42 s            hello-4-1616077440
02:25:03 PM     02:25:45 PM     42 s            hello-4-1616077500
```

Additionally, you'll likely want to create exceptions and error handling to make this script work as expected in all cases.